# "Use of unassigned local variable" compiler error for switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, io, switch-statement

I have the following C# code:

```
AnimalTypeEnum animal;
string s = Console.ReadLine();
switch (s.ToLower())
{
case "dog":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.DOG;
    break;
case "cat":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.CAT;
    break;
case "rabbit":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.RABBIT;
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine(animal); #compiler error here
```

I get this error on the last line: `Use of unassigned local variable 'animal'`. I know that it's because `animal` may not have a value depending on the user input, so how do I fix that?

Ideally I'd like to show an error message if an unknown animal type was entered and make the user input the value again.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a `default:` clause.  Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to fix it, using recursive calls instead of needing to catch and throw exceptions, or use a loop (loops in a case like this obfuscate the meaning in my opinion; too much about how you're doing it instead of what you're doing):

```
private static AnimalTypeEnum GetAnimalFromInput()
{
    AnimalTypeEnum animal;
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (s.ToLower())
    {
        case "dog":
            animal = AnimalTypeEnum.DOG;
            break;
        case "cat":
            animal = AnimalTypeEnum.CAT;
            break;
        case "rabbit":
            animal = AnimalTypeEnum.RABBIT;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine(s + " is not valid, please try again");
            animal = GetAnimalFromInput();
            break;
    }
    return animal;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AnimalTypeEnum animal = GetAnimalFromInput();

    Console.WriteLine(animal);
}
```

I'll also note that it's good practice to refactor your switch into an if/else chain, using `if (s.Equals("dog", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))` (or the appropriate case-insensitive comparison) to keep it working in other cultures.  Of course, this may not apply to your scenario (e.g. test/homework app, or something that will only possibly be used in your culture).

---

**Update:** Thanks to Mennan Kara for the idea, if your values (e.g. `"dog"`) will always match the enum's values (e.g. `DOG`), then you can use `Enum.TryParse` to improve your code:

```
private static AnimalTypeEnum GetAnimalFromInput()
{
    AnimalTypeEnum animal;
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Enum.TryParse(s, true, out animal))
        return animal;
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s + " is not valid, please try again");
        return GetAnimalFromInput();
    }
}
```

If you need the flexibility of having them separate, then keep your existing switch.

Answer (score 2):

In case `s.ToLower()` is something else that `dog`, `cat` or `rabbit`, `animal` has no value.

You should add default in your switch for that case:

```
switch (s.ToLower())
{
case "dog":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.DOG;
    break;
case "cat":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.CAT;
    break;
case "rabbit":
    animal = AnimalTypeEnum.RABBIT;
    break;
default:
    animal = ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: But in the default case, I don't want to give `animal` a value, I want the value to be input again.

Comment: @Dr.SteveBrule Then throw an exception. You could then catch the exception and ask he use another value.

Comment: If you want to ask again you need to place this in a loop. And exceptions are a bad advice here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If the code I've wrote is in a method that returns a `AnimalTypeEnum` from a `string`, then how is `ArgumentException` a bad advice?

Comment: You didn't write the method. And since it's proccessing user input it should be `bool TryGetAnimalTypeFromString(...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
AnimalTypeEnum animal;
var s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(!Enum.TryParse(s, true, out animal) ? "Not a valid animal" : animal.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a default `ENUM` for any animal unknown to *your code*. You could even make your code to learn new animals. For instance.

```
switch (s.ToLower())
{
default:
    animal = AnimalType.Unkown;
    break;
}
```

or

```
default:
    animal = new MakeEnum(s.ToLower());
    myEnumList.Add(animal);
    break;
```

Your `MakeEnum` basically just needs to check length of current number of enums, and make a new enum using the number or some other parameter.